# Clear all JFrame selections

Tags: swing, events, focus, mouse, lwjgl

I have embedded LWJGL-canvas (in JPanel, which is in JSplitPane) in my JFrame. And I have a JMenuBar. Problem is LWJGL capturing focus and is not firing swing mouse events.
So if I, for example, click at LWJGL canvas while one of JMenu is popped up - swing will ignore (actually not receive any) event and popup window won't disappear.

[image]

I aslo tried to revalidate the menubar and the whole JFrame, nothing worked for me for now.
In my case Robot is not the solution - I don't want to use this, it will cause inconvinencies.
Btw, I tried doing something like this:

```
MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent(mainFrame, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, false);
for (MouseListener m : menuBar.getMouseListeners()) {
    m.mousePressed(me);
}
```

But this also had no effect.
Is there any other solutions? How can I clear all the selections in JFrame, like when user minimizes the window or presses WIN key?

Comment: Oh thanks, Captain Obvious. I like to know how to clear selections, not to receive an event. I have read about mixing LWJGL and Swing, but that's not the clue

Answer (score 0):

You are able to get the MouseClick from LWJGL. Now you can call
[`MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().clearSelectedPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/MenuSelectionManager.html#clearSelectedPath%28%29) 
 to close the menus.